# Fortran I/O, first read is EOF?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77, fortran95

I'm trying to use some old FORTRAN code with some new Java code which works in Windows(as an exe) but not in OS X.  I try to build it in eclipse and I get

```
make: *** [all] Segmentation fault: 11
```

so I go to terminal and do it that way, even different compilers but still the same result:

Running OS X 10.7.5 and gfortran-4.2 made 
with standard -c and -o commands

```
Program foo
open(unit = 1, file = 'variables.txt',IOSTAT= iost)
    write(*,*)iost
    read(1,*) P
    write(*,*)P
...
end program foo
```

the program builds manually but the output is:

```
0
At line 13 of file Cubic42.f
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

I have also seen this error:

```
list in: end of file
apparent state: unit 88 named variables
last format: list io
lately reading sequential formatted external IO
Abort
```

It shows that IOSTAT returns 0, which means the file is good?
But it will not read the file, even if I change the unit# to say, 88.. and even if I change the CR to mac, windows, or unix.

It seems to be only a problem with the input/output, if i hardcode variables, for example, the program works.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**
Here is the variables.txt file

```
-9999
15.6
500
150.9
48.98
0.000
```

there is a carriage return at the end, and it doesn't matter if i change the -9999 to positive

**Edit2**

I deleted the text file from the directory and remade the .f to look like this:

```
program foo
   implicit none
    real a, b, c, d
   open(unit = 1, file = 'variables.2txt', action='write')
   write(1, *) -6666
   write(1, *) 6.15
    write(1, *) -321
    write(1, *) 5.16
   close(1)

    open(unit = 2, file = 'variables.2txt', action='read',form='FORMATTED')
    read(2, *) a
            write(*,*) a
    read(2, *) b
            write(*,*) b
    read(2, *) c
            write(*,*) c
    read(2, *) d
            write(*,*) d
    close(2)

end program foo
```

Then I compiled it.
Output is:

```
  -6666.000    
   6.150000    
  -321.0000    
   5.160000
```

as expected, but variables.2txt is nowhere to be found! I'm very confused, please help.

**Edit3**
I have found the phantom file.  It is located at /users/me/phantom.txt
So the question is, how do I make the file save in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Could you show the content (first few lines) ouf your input file?

Comment: input file is at edit1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a very similar error message to yours

```
           0
At line 4 of file proba.f (unit = 1, file = 'variables.txt')
```

when running your code on Linux with a file `variables.txt` where I explicitly set the end of line characters according to the old MAC convention to `^M` (instead of Unix's `^J`). So, I guess, it is an EOL-convention problem. You could eventually try to write two lines to a file and investigate that file in order to decide which EOL-convention gfortran expects on your system:

```
program foo
  implicit none
  open(unit = 1, file = 'variables.txt', action='write')
  write(1, *) -9999
  write(1, *) 15.6
  close(1)
end program foo
```

Also, I'd definitely go for a more recent gfortran compiler (current stable is version 4.7.2).

Comment: OK, that seems to have worked better, however, the text file is neither created (if missing) or rewritten (if present) Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, now with some more tinkering I've found that after running that program making a file called variables.txt with only two values, now my subsequent attempts (with different text files of the same name) fail (EOF) after two reads when I know there are more entries than that.

Comment: I've now run into a slight and very strange problem: the text file seems to be written to and read from but not visible.  Update is above in edit2

Comment: Without explicit path the file will be created in the current working directory. If you execute your program from a terminal, that is the directory in which you are, when you enter the name of your program. If you start your program via the GUI by clicking on it, it depends on your system settings. You can however open the file using an explicit path (e.g. `open(unit=1, file='/directory/of/executable/variable.txt' ...`) then it will be created in the specified directory.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to set the path to the executable directory but I'm thinking maybe FORTRAN isn't a very good way to do this.  Instead, do you think it would be better if I used Java (the calling program) to write the path to, say, the first line of variables.txt?

Comment: Not sure, if I understand 100% your problem. How do you find the file variables.txt in your Fortran program, if the correct path to it is stored in the file?

Comment: Fortran is doing it for me just as above,     file='variables.txt'.  In Windows, the path seems to be relative to the .exe, that's great.  But using the same code in OS X, the path defaults to /users/me/ which isn't so great. Even if i supply a variables.txt in the executable directory, it still creates a new one in /users/me/.  This program is being run as a part of a larger Java program (actually, the text file being read by fortran is created by Java). I would like to keep everything together. So I'm wondering if I should just supply the Fortran programs with the path via Java and txt file.

Comment: I just realized.. how is Fortran going to find the text file to begin with?...
So the question is, how do I get the path of the Fortran executable programmatically, and then use that path to specify the file path? in Java it would be something like:
 
    String path = this.getResource().getPath().toString +"variables.txt";

Is there something similar in FORTRAN?

Comment: That's somewhat tricky, but this is not the scenario, you usually want when using Unix. Executables are often installed at places, where the user executing them has no right to write into. You rather want to write things below the users home directory (or to /tmp), where the user has full access rights.

Comment: Ok, for this project I can use the /tmp folder since the user won't have to retrieve any sort of txt file.  But what if I wanted to specify the path relative to the executable? (I am assuming the user has full rights)